System.InvalidOperationException: A type named 'StartupProduction' or 'Startup' could not be found in assembly
I am trying to publish ASP.NET Core Web API to Azure with GitHub CI/CD. I am using completely default and generated WeatherForecast in .net 8.0. My problem is that GitHub actions fail everytime with following error:

I also tried to update Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package, but the error persists. If you know how to fix this problem, please let me know. Thanks!
EDIT:
Here is my repo with testing project: https://github.com/SmutnyJan/backend-testing
The workflow is generated by VS but there were still errors, so I had to change couple of things:
First error I encountered was that one:

I thought this is caused by .gitignore file, so I started commiting release folder yet the problem still persisted. Then I realised it is searching for the dll file in wrong directory which is specified in yaml file. So I made some adjustments aswell. After that this problem with dll was fixed, but I got the error mentioned in title.
I hope it clarifies everything!

Can you please share the Progam.cs file.

If possible please share your code repo.

Update your Visual Studio version and create a new app and check once.

It seems the type is defined in another assembly (project), but the building context doesn't contain it. If you build the app within docker, make sure the project, that contains the type, is included to the context and copied to the container.

Can you please share the pipeline?

I added link to my repo with all the information needed.

I have checked your repo and I make it works in my side, for more details, you can check my .yml file and the git action records in my repo( repo link in my answer below ).

So, for anyone who would come across this issue:
There are currently two things you need to edit in generated yml file:


Check that version on swashbuckle matches with version stated in yml file
Check that your path to final dll file matches with your structure.


Love you man <3

I found that this problem is related to the structure of the project code you uploaded. There is an extra layer of WebApplication1 folder in your project.


It works properly in myside, here is the test result.


My test steps
1. I forked your repo and I can't reproduce the issue, maybe it related to the environment.
2. And I found the folder structure is strange, then I use your code and create this repo in my account. ( https://github.com/Jason446620/backend-testing-01)
3. [ OPTIONAL ] If you still want keep this structure in in you side, you should consider how to custom the build/publish path in your .yml file.

Where did you find the .yaml file? Or did you create your own? Because I am using the pre-generated from VS2022.

@JanSmutný https://github.com/SmutnyJan/backend-testing/tree/main/.github/workflows

@JanSmutný That's not important, please follow my suggestion, and make the publish file structure like mine, the issue would be fixed.

So what should I change in your yml file? It is actually important, because your yml looks way different.

Hi @JanSmutný, could you tell me how you deploy your azure webapp ？ And my detailed steps are 1 open azure portal -> 2 Find the App and click  Deployment Center - >  connect github repo under the settings tab.

@JanSmutný I am not creating the yml in github action page like  following the official steps.  All the steps are completed in azure portal.
